# Logging via Dependency injection vs implicit dependency with Unit Test

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a class that requires logging using Log4net. Below are two possible solutions consiering unit testing.

Solution 1:

```
public class Car{
  ILog log;
  public Car(ILog log){
  this.log = log
  }

   //use logging for other methods
}
```

Solution 2:

```
public class Car
  ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Car));
  public Car(){
  }

   //use logging for other methods
}
```

Questions:

1) Which way is better in general?

2) For solution 2, How should I replace the logger in unit test.

Comment: Better how?  This seems a matter of opinion to me.  I've seen both ways and I'm sure each author though their's was best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a static Factory (LogManager), but a non-static Factory could be better. Then you can pass in the factory itself, and the unit test can create its own ILog object using it. This makes it easier to mock.

You would still need a way to make the factory, but you can pass in an instrumented test version to help with the tests.

Comment: Using Ctor dependency injection is easy to understand and use. But its downloadside is to pass it for every instantiation. Using implicit dependency might cause surpises down the road.